# How to show custom error messages below text field?

Tags: 7, forms, comments, paging, nodes

I want to display custom error messages below that text field in `comments form`. Currently it displays all error messages above the page which is not acceptable.

I'm using [this](http://drupalet.com/demo/drupal/dotted/blog?style_blog=timeline) theme for [my blog](http://wadhwablog.netbizlabs.com/blog). I also used [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1324924) but it's not working. As I'm new in drupal I'm struggling with this, please suggest any solution.

Comment: If you are familiar with jquery, you can achieve this by using jquery also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need go to your theme's template folder and edit **page.tpl.php**'

Look for `<?php print $messages; ?>` and move it below `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>`

Thanks for the [note](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213908/how-to-show-custom-error-messages-below-text-field/213921?noredirect=1#comment-261524) @Kevin. If you wish, you can add if statements around the `<?php print $messages; ?>` that check the page url and/or content type if you need to have them appear below only for certain pages.

Comment: Note that this is a global change, all messages from drupal_set_message() will now appear below the page content, which may or may not be acceptable.